# Unable to break on empty string

Tags: python, conditional-statements, break

I'm attempting to get not more than 10 user inputs. The user can choose to stop giving input by inputing an empty string

```
container_size = []
for i in range(10):
   while True:
      container_size.append(float(input('What is the size of your container?: ')))
      if input('What is the size of your container?: ') == '':
         break
         if i <= 1:
            refund = 0.10
         else:
            refund = 0.25
print(refund)
```

I keep getting an error when trying to break if no input is given. What can I do? I am also getting more than 10 inputs.

Comment: Your other code is not reachable, because break is there.

Comment: The `break` exits from the inner most loop, in this case the `while` loop. Did you want to break from the `for` loop?

Comment: You shouldn't have two loops - the `for` loop will execute the `while` loop 10 times, and the `while` loop contains two input statements so you have no control over the max number of loops. Also, if the user does input an empty string `float(input('What is the size of your container?: '))` will give you a ValueError

Comment: The goal is to break when there is no user input. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
container_size = []
refund = []
i = 0
for i in range(10):
   try:
      container_size.append(float(input('What is the size of your container?: ')))
   except ValueError:         
      break
for x in container_size:
   if x <= 1:
      refund.append(0.10)
   else:
      refund.append(0.25)
print(sum(refund))
```

I corrected the code already. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You call for input() twice: once for add to container, and second time in the if. So for every iteration, you are asking for 2 inputs. Therefore you have a total of 20 inputs instead of ten. Put it in a variable, and ask if the variable is empty/add variable to container.

your `break` statement currently refer to the if statement and not the while, because it interacts with closest statement which is the if. You can overcome this by using flag and check it at the end of the while statement.